# nodejs refactor if condition function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function

```
//===========[Ranks depeonds on the totalPoints]================
// Ranks Discribution: 1 = Bronze / 2 = Silver / 3 = Gold / 4 = Platinum / 5 = Diamond / 6 = Master / 7 = Challenger
// If was used instead of switch for performance improvment
const rank = (totalPoints, pointsRank) => {
    if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[0] && totalPoints < pointsRank[1]) {
        return ({
            rank: 1,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[1] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[1] && totalPoints < pointsRank[2]) {
        return ({
            rank: 2,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[2] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[2] && totalPoints < pointsRank[3]) {
        return ({
            rank: 3,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[3] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[3] && totalPoints < pointsRank[4]) {
        return ({
            rank: 4,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[4] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[4] && totalPoints < pointsRank[5]) {
        return ({
            rank: 5,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[5] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[5] && totalPoints < pointsRank[6]) {
        return ({
            rank: 6,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[6] - totalPoints)
        })
    } else if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[6]) {
        return ({
            rank: 7,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: 0
        })
    } else {
        return ({
            rank: 0,
            pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[0] - totalPoints)
        })
    }
}
module.exports = rank
```

and I call it like this

```
            let pointsRank = [150, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 5500]
            let totalPoints = 1200
            rank(totalPoints, pointsRank)
```

output

```
{ rank: 3, pointsLeftForNextRank: 600 }
```

how can I improve this function? I feel like that I wrote a lot of code which can be refactored into something smaller
like a small amount of code that does the same functionality
also, I need to know if am violating any of the SOLID principles

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Before offering any solution for simplifying the code, you have to fix a flaw in the logic: since the array has 7 elements, we have 8 different intervals, but you have just 7 ranks (and 7 conditions), there should be 8 ranks. One of them is lacking, namely: what if the points fall between 150 and 500? What should be the returned object?

Comment: you are right my bad i edited the code now it works fine. thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the ingredients to remove all of the `if` logic, which would quickly become a maintenance nightmare.

```js
function rank(points, ranks) {
  for (let index = 0, { length } = ranks; index < length; ++index) {
    if (points < ranks[index]) {
      return {
        rank: index,
        pointsLeftForNextRank: ranks[index] - points
      };
    }
  }

  return {
    rank: ranks.length,
    pointsLeftForNextRank: 0
  }
}
```

This works because you can easily compare the points value against every rank in ranks and stop iterating once the points needed for a rank exceed the points one has. As the final rank has a special case for the `pointsLeftForNextRank` always being `0` I simply made the function return that case if all ranks have been reached.

To be *that person*; your expected answer is off.
`{ rank: 3, pointsLeftForNextRank: 600 }`
for rank 3 to be true (which it is), the points needed to the next rank is 800, which makes the expected output:

```js
{ rank: 3, pointsLeftForNextRank: 800 } // 2000 - 1200 = 800
```

Answer (score 1):

First I would refactor the conditions and results as functions. For example, you can create `smaller`, `bigger` and `between` as helper functions. As well as a `result` function that will deliver the result.

```js
const rank = (total, ranks) => {
  const smaller = i =>  total <= ranks[i-1];
  const bigger = i => total >= ranks[i-1];
  const between = (i,j) => ranks[i-1] <= total && total < ranks[j-1];
  const result = rank => ({ 
    rank, 
    pointsLeftForNextRank: (ranks[rank-1] - total) > 0 ? ranks[rank-1] - total : 0,
  });

  if (smaller(1)) {
    return result(1);
  } else if (between(1, 2)) {
    return result(2);
  } else if (between(2, 3)) {
    return result(3);
  } else if (between(3, 4)) {
    return result(4);
  } else if (between(4, 5)) {
    return result(5);
  } else if (between(5, 6)) {
    return result(6);
  } else if (bigger(7)) {
    return result(7);
  }
}
```

It's still quite verbose, and you can refactor by handling all cases with `between`. This allows us to automate the verification even for the edge cases that were previously handled by `smaller` or `bigger`.

So you can search inside `pointsRank` for the first rank that follows the condition `between(i,i+1)`. Then call `result` on this resulting index *+ 1*.

```js
const rank = (total, ranks) => {
  const between = (r1,r2) => {
    if (!ranks[r1-1]) return total <= ranks[r2-1];
    if (!ranks[r2-1]) return total >= ranks[r1-1];
    return ranks[r1-1] <= total && total < ranks[r2-1];
  }
  const result = rank => ({ 
    rank: rank == -1 ? ranks.length : rank, 
    pointsLeftForNextRank: ranks[rank] - total || 0,
  });

  return result(ranks.findIndex((_, i) => between(i,i+1)));
}

console.log(rank(1200, [150, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 5500]));
```

Comment: hello thanks very much for this great answer. but it should return `{ rank: 3, pointsLeftForNextRank: 600 }`

Comment: @mohamedadel, I have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```js
 const rank = (totalPoints, pointsRank) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < pointsRank.length; i++) {
        if (i !== pointsRank.length) {
            if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[i] && totalPoints < pointsRank[i + 1])
                return { rank: i + 1, pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[i + 1] - totalPoints) }
        } else if (i === pointsRank.length) {
            if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[6])
                return { rank: i + 1, pointsLeftForNextRank: 0 }
        }
    }
}
/* module.exports = rank */ // uncomment this code

let pointsRank = [150, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 5500]
let totalPoints = 1200
let result = rank(totalPoints, pointsRank);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: it works great but I edited the code because if the points fall between 150 and 500 it would return nothing  can you check that edit and edit your answer if possible? also, some explanation will be great

Comment: @mohamedadel please have a look over the answer , i have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
const rank = (totalPoints, pointsRank) => {
    let currentIndex;
    for (currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < pointsRank.length; currentIndex++) {
        if (totalPoints >= pointsRank[currentIndex - 1] && totalPoints < pointsRank[currentIndex]) {
            break;
        }
    }
    var closest =
    {
        rank: currentIndex,
        pointsLeftForNextRank: (pointsRank[currentIndex] - totalPoints)
    };
    return closest;
}
let pointsRank = [150, 500, 1000, 2000, 3500, 5000, 5500]
let totalPoints = 1200
console.log(rank(totalPoints, pointsRank));
```

Comment: Perfect. but onething for values less than 150 it should return 
for example totalPoints = 140 it should return 
`"rank": 0,
            "pointsLeftForNextRank": 10`
other than that it's perfect

Comment: also it would be great if you added some explanation since i am a beginner :)